# Spark Scala : Nullify columns keeping the same column DataType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After reading Dataframe, I need to nullify some columns, (Columns having PII info) but keeping the original column DataType.

I tried this:

```
 implicit class DataFrameImplicits (dataFrame: DataFrame) {

     def withPIIColumnsNullified(piiCols : Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {

      piiCols.foldLeft(dataFrame) { (outputDf, piiCol) => {
          outputDf.withColumn(piiCol, it(null))
        }
      }
    }

 }
```

In my logic:

```
 val piiCols = //column list needs to be nullified
 var df = //read the datafrom HDFS

 df = df.withPIIColumnsNullified(piiCols)
```

But above method changed the original column type into 'null type', making it impossible to save as Parquet.

How to keep the original DataType while doing this conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code.

You have to pass `Seq[(String,String)]` to `withPIIColumnsNullified` function.

First string is `column name` & second string is `column data type`. Inside your function cast that column with value of second parameter.

```
implicit class DataFrameImplicits (dataFrame: DataFrame) {
     def withPIIColumnsNullified(cols : Seq[(String,String)]) : DataFrame = {
      cols.foldLeft(dataFrame) { (outputDf, cols) => {
          outputDf.withColumn(cols._1, lit(null).cast(cols._2))
        }
      }
    }
 }

var df = //read the datafrom HDFS
val colsAndDt = df.schema.fields.map(d => (d.name,d.dataType.typeName)).toSeq

df = df.withPIIColumnsNullified(colsAndDt)
```